# Why is ㅂ sometimes pronounced as ㅁ? What are the rules?

Tags: pronunciation, hangul

I'm brand new to learning Korean -- I have studied a little bit of Hangul to learn the sounds, and I just started Lesson 1 of *Elementary Korean, 2nd ed.* by King & Yeon.

In this lesson there is a list of basic expressions. I am confused in a couple of places where I see the letter ㅂ but the pronunciation guide clearly shows the pronunciation as "m". But in other places, the pronunciation of the same character is "p" or "b" as I would expect.

For example, in Lesson 1, basic expression 5:

...입니다. (English: I'm...)

the pronunciation is shown as "...imnida"

I looked in *Sounds of Korean* (Choo & O'Grady), but didn't find any rules for when ㅂ should be pronounced as "m" -- maybe I just missed it?

Note: I am trying to avoid Romanization; I only consulted it here when I noticed the discrepancy between what I was hearing on the audio and what I was seeing in Hangul.

Comment: There are the standard pronunciation rules written in Korean. Please refer to [this table](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Korean-Thai-Lexicon-for-Natural-Language-Processing-Mahahing-Seresangtakul/706cafd664d8c6f84a41a9f8cfe92addf1069afe/figure/3).

Comment: @Klmo perfect, those are exactly the kind of rules I was looking for -- thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of *nasalization*: when ㅂ or ㅍ as the final consonant of a syllable is followed by an initial ㄴ or ㅁ in the next syllable, the ㅂ or ㅍ is pronounced as ㅁ.

See [this table](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Korean-Thai-Lexicon-for-Natural-Language-Processing-Mahahing-Seresangtakul/706cafd664d8c6f84a41a9f8cfe92addf1069afe/figure/3) for additional rules that show how pronunciation can change. See also section 4.9 and 4.9.1 in *Sounds of Korean* for more information on nasalization.

Answer (score 0):

As I studied about phonetic when ㅂ or ㅍ meet ㄴ or ㅁ pronunciation chang to ㅁ
like this word 앞문 but the way we pronunce is 암문.